# How many $5$-digit numbers can be made from digits in the number $75226522$?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having troubles with this one:

How many $5$-digit numbers can be made from digits in the number $75226522$ ?

So there is: one seven, one six, two fives, and four twos in that number.

So I guess I need to use combination with repetition but I'm having trouble with understanding this.

I know how many $8$-digit numbers there are: $$ \frac{8!}{4!2!}$$ But I'm clueless in $5$-digit case

Comment: Hint: Looks like you need to choose any 5 digits from that number, and each time you take one of the digits you are not replacing it.

Comment: I would start off with numbers with 4 2's in them, then numbers with 3 2's (can also have 2 5's is a special case), then numbers with 2 x 2's, then 1 , then zero

Comment: 4 2's is  3 choices of 5th number, 5 ways of arranging them,  3 x 5 = 15

Comment: 3 2's + 2 5's = 5!/2!/3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number with no 5's, so either three or four 2's: $$\frac{5!}{3!} + 2 \times \frac{5!}{4!}.$$
Number with one 5, so either two, three, or four 2's: $$\frac{5!}{2!} + 2 \times \frac{5!}{3!} + \frac{5!}{4!}.$$
Number with two 5's, so either one, two, or three 2's: $$\frac{5!}{2!} + 2 \times \frac{5!}{2! 2!} + \frac{5!}{2! 3!}.$$
Now adding these three numbers together should give the right result.

Comment: For the situation where there are no 5s and three 2s, I think it should be 4!/2! ?

Comment: Why so? We're still permuting 5 digits...

Comment: Is there a generic solution for this type of problem. Or it is always about considering different cases ?

Comment: Not one I'm aware of. It would certainly become painful with too many more repeated digits, but you can at least be systematic about breaking into cases.

Comment: @Mr.Chip Never mind, I made a mistake.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Thanks @Mr.Chip

Comment: In which of the three considered numbers are 77777 (or aaaaa), please?

Comment: The interpretation I have of the question is that the 5-digit number is to be formed without replacement from the digits of $75226522$. So there is only one 7 to play with.

Comment: This interpretation discard many examples, in particular 15 cases with aaaa (five for each of b,c,d other distinct digits: baaaa,abaaa,aabaa,aaaba,aaaab)

Answer (score 2):

Add up the following:

- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{2222}\color\green{ 5}\color\orange{ }\color\lightblue{ }$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{4!}\color\green{1!}\color\orange{  }\color\lightblue{  }}= 5$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{2222}\color\green{  }\color\orange{6}\color\lightblue{ }$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{4!}\color\green{  }\color\orange{1!}\color\lightblue{  }}= 5$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{2222}\color\green{  }\color\orange{ }\color\lightblue{7}$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{4!}\color\green{  }\color\orange{  }\color\lightblue{1!}}= 5$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{ 222}\color\green{55}\color\orange{ }\color\lightblue{ }$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{3!}\color\green{2!}\color\orange{  }\color\lightblue{  }}=10$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{ 222}\color\green{ 5}\color\orange{6}\color\lightblue{ }$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{3!}\color\green{1!}\color\orange{1!}\color\lightblue{  }}=20$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{ 222}\color\green{ 5}\color\orange{ }\color\lightblue{7}$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{3!}\color\green{1!}\color\orange{  }\color\lightblue{1!}}=20$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{ 222}\color\green{  }\color\orange{6}\color\lightblue{7}$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{3!}\color\green{  }\color\orange{1!}\color\lightblue{1!}}=20$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{  22}\color\green{55}\color\orange{6}\color\lightblue{ }$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{2!}\color\green{2!}\color\orange{1!}\color\lightblue{  }}=30$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{  22}\color\green{55}\color\orange{ }\color\lightblue{7}$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{2!}\color\green{2!}\color\orange{  }\color\lightblue{1!}}=30$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{  22}\color\green{ 5}\color\orange{6}\color\lightblue{7}$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{2!}\color\green{1!}\color\orange{1!}\color\lightblue{1!}}=60$
- The number of ways to rearrange $\color\red{   2}\color\green{55}\color\orange{6}\color\lightblue{7}$, which is $\frac{5!}{\color\red{1!}\color\green{2!}\color\orange{1!}\color\lightblue{1!}}=60$

Hence the total number of ways is $5+5+5+10+20+20+20+30+30+60+60=265$.